# How do i connect the last drawed point with the next one ?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                points.Add(new PointF(e.X * xFactor, e.Y * yFactor));
                pictureBox2.Invalidate();
                label5.Visible = true;
                label5.Text = String.Format("X: {0}; Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y);
                counter += 1;
                label6.Visible = true;
                label6.Text = counter.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen p;
            p = new Pen(Brushes.Green);
            foreach (PointF pt in points)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, pt.X, pt.Y, 3f, 3f);
            }
            foreach (PointF pt in points)
            {
                if (points.Count > 1)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, pt.X, pt.Y, 3f, 3f);
                }
            }
        }
```

When i click on pictureBox1 its drawing a point on pictureBox2.

In the pictureBox2 paint im doing a loop over the List of points and drawing.

Then i did another loop and in the DrawLine i want to connect the last point with the next one with a line how can i do it ?

Tried this one now:

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
            {
                if (points.Count > 1)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, points[i].X, points[i].Y, points[i+1].X, points[i+1].Y);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

But this will connect only the first two points not all the others.

I want that each time i make a click and draw a new point it will be automatic connected with a line to the last drawed point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `break` only allows one line to be drawn.  Since you need to access 2 points at a time, you have to be careful to keep the array index within bounds.  If you pick the 2nd point by doing `i+1` then you need your `for` loop to stop when `i < points.Count - 1` that gives you room at the end.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `GraphicsPath` take a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to do this  for example to draw a line use this

```
private void AddLineExample(PaintEventArgs e)
{

    //Create a path and add a symetrical triangle using AddLine.
    GraphicsPath myPath = new GraphicsPath();
    myPath.AddLine(30, 30, 60, 60);
    myPath.AddLine(60, 60, 0, 60);
    myPath.AddLine(0, 60, 30, 30);    
    // Draw the path to the screen.
    Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
    e.Graphics.DrawPath(myPen, myPath);
}
```